# JOIN on conditional field

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a table of messages:

```
id
sender_id
recipient_id
```

I want to pull all the messages of user (id:**1**) where he was either the **sender** or the **recipient** and JOIN the "other guy" he was talking to.

something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `message`
LEFT JOIN `user` AS u ON IF(sender_id != 1, sender_id = u.id, recipient_id = u.id)
WHERE sender_id=1 OR recipient_id=1
```

the reason I don't join both the **sender** and **recipient** is that I already have the user I'm searching on, so I think it's a waste to join him on every message - **unless you tell me otherwise!**

This query I got from another SO question, but I've read it's not efficient at all, so what will be a better query?

Comment: INNER JOINs are faster than LEFT JOINs, and I can't see a reason to use a LEFT JOIN here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way could work but the join won't use an index. If you want a fast join you need something like `joined_table_indexed_field = some_expression`, for example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `message` m
JOIN `user` AS u ON u.id = IF(m.sender_id = 1, m.recipient_id , m.sender_id)
WHERE m.sender_id=1 OR m.recipient_id=1
```

In this case @Grim's solution is better because it doesn't rely on mysql to perform an union index_merge for the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
SELECT *
FROM message
JOIN users ON (message.sender_id = 1 AND user.id = message.recipient_id)
           OR (message.recipient_id = 1 AND user.id = message.sender_id)
```

Note that there are various other ways of doing this in a more performant fashion.  This is the most straightforward method that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a union:

```
(
SELECT * FROM `message`
INNER JOIN `user` u ON u.id = recipient_id
WHERE sender_id = 1
) UNION (
SELECT * FROM `message` 
INNER JOIN `user` u ON u.id = sender_id 
WHERE recipient_id = 1
)
```